# Most occurring element in an array using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I had tried the following code to get most occurring element in an array. It is working well but the only problem is when there are two or more elements having the same number of occurrence and equal to most occurring element, it just shows the first element scanned. Please help me through this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,a[5];
    int popular = a[0];
    int temp=0, tempCount, count=1;
    cout << "Enter the elements: " << endl;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        tempCount = 0;
        temp=a[i];
        tempCount++;
        for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(a[j] == temp)
            {
                tempCount++;
                if(tempCount > count)
                {
                    popular = temp;
                    count = tempCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Most occured element is: " <<  popular;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to output both the numbers in case of a tie?

Comment: so, what have you tried?

Comment: @Lakshayarora: how would you solve this using a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Because you are a newbie, let me give you an advise: **Avoid `using namespace std;`**. Read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to understand why is a bad practice.

Comment: @Lakshayarora: that's a horrible advice to a beginner. how's that going to help him?

Comment: 1st improve formatting! 2nd think over where you're going to declare your variables!

Comment: @g-makulik What's wrong in variables' current places of declaration?

Comment: Why so many down-votes?

Comment: @khajvah Declaring the loop counter variable outside the loop declaration is usually a bad idea.

Comment: It will be easier if you first sort your array.

Comment: @g-makulik ok, yeah, in case of `for` loop, there is no point to declare outside.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Repeat solution twice and change two line.

```
if (count>max_count)
    max_count = count;
```

with:

```
if (count==max_count)
    cout << a[i] << endl;
```

Solution:

```
int a[5];
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
   cin>>a[i];

int max_count = 0;

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   int count=1;
   for (int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
       if (a[i]==a[j])
           count++;
   if (count>max_count)
      max_count = count;
}

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   int count=1;
   for (int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
       if (a[i]==a[j])
           count++;
   if (count==max_count)
       cout << a[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks @hasan this is the perfect solution for this program :)

Comment: Can you accept it as the answer to your question and upvote please :)

Comment: I tried but not having enough reputation . I would up vote after qualifying for it.

Comment: How could you make it choose the larger of the two when a tie occurs?

Comment: @BreonThibodeaux the solution prints all those values. easliy you can modify the solution to only get the largest number. serach for max value on array.

Answer (score 3):

To collect all answers and not just the first one, 
you may use `std::vector<int> popular` instead of `int popular`.

then when `tempCount == count`, `popular.push_back(temp);`,

when `tempCount > count`, `popular.clear(); popular.push_back(temp);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution will work better and it is shorter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int topCount=0, count, topElement, array[10];

for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
{
    cin>>array[i];
}

for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ;i++)
{
    count=0;
    for (int j=0 ; j<10 ; j++)
    {
        if (array[i]==array[j]) count++;
    }
    if (count>topCount)
    {
        topCount=count;
        topElement=array[i];
    }
}

cout<<topElement<<" "<<topCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a templatize solution:

```
template <class Iter, class ValType>
void findMostCommon_ (Iter first, Iter last)
{      
   typename std::vector<ValType> pop;
   int popular_cnt = 0;

   for (Iter it = first;   it != last;    ++it)
   {
      int temp_cnt = 0;

      for (Iter it2 = it + 1;  it2 != last;      ++it2)
         if (*it == *it2)
            ++temp_cnt;

      if (temp_cnt)
      {
         if (temp_cnt > popular_cnt)
         {
            popular_cnt = temp_cnt;
            pop.clear();
            pop.push_back(*it);
         }
         else if (temp_cnt == popular_cnt)
         {
            pop.push_back(*it);
         }
      }
   }

   if (pop.empty())  // all numbers unique
   {
      cout << "Could not find most popular" << endl;
   }
   else`enter code here`
   {
      cout << "Most popular numbers: ";

      for (typename std::vector<ValType>::const_iterator it = pop.begin(), lst = pop.end();   it != lst;    ++it)
         cout << (*it) << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on this answer?

Comment: It will get a list of most repeated numbers for any type of container that supports iterators including c-style arrays: Ex:

Answer (score 0):

Complete function for this type of problem:

```
int calcMode(int array[], int array_size)
{
int topCount=0, count, topElement = 10;

for ( int i=0 ; i<array_size ;i++)
{
    count=0;
    for (int j=0 ; j<array_size ; j++)
    {
        if (array[i]==array[j]) count++;
    }
    if (count>=topCount)
    {
        topCount=count;
        if (topElement > array[i])
            topElement=array[i];
    }
}

return topElement;
}
```